# how to add footer to image on javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I want to add a footer to images like flyers, the footer could be another image or just text added for the user
The job will be like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5M1C.png)

And i have to add text or another image like footer

Answer (score 0):

This should be HTML basic knowledge: You can do this with nested HTML elements. Eg. put the `<img>` into a `<div>` and add other elements into the `<div>` too. Another approach would be using the image as a CSS `backgroundImage` of the `<div>` and add other elements (divs, images) in the `<div>` as children (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

All those elements can of course be create in Javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

To place the elements at the position you like you need to use CSS. Have a look at CSS positioning: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp